# Markov chain converges to the same steady state for different initial probability vectors.

Tags: probability, markov-chains, steady-state

I was asked to write a code to simulate the following Markov chain, and find the PMF of the random variable $X$:
[image: Stock Exchange]

The code I've written for simulating the given Markov chain:

```
import numpy as np

POWER = 20

P = np.array(([0.3, 0.2, 0.5], [0.4, 0.3, 0.3], [0.3, 0.4, 0.3]))

p1 = np.array([1,0,0])
p2 = np.array([0,1,0])
p3 = np.array([0,0,1])


p_POWER = np.linalg.matrix_power(P,POWER)

print(p1 @ p_POWER)
print(p2 @ p_POWER)
print(p3 @ p_POWER)
```

The Result of the code:

```
[0.33035714 0.30357143 0.36607143]
[0.33035714 0.30357143 0.36607143]
[0.33035714 0.30357143 0.36607143]
```

I cannot understand why this is the case, my best guess is it has to do something with the graph of my Markov chain being complete, but I cannot prove it. I don't find the results intuitive, and would appreciate and help on the matter.

Comment: Consider an analogous example. You have a cup of coffee and a cup of iced tea. One has initial state “hot” and the other “cold”, but both end up, in the limiting/steady state/equilibrium  distribution of “room temperature”. This behavior of the steady state distribution’s independence of the initial condition ought to be rather intuitive.

Comment: That sheds some light on it, but does a Markov chain need a specific characteristic for this to be true?

Comment: indeed, this is not always true. But an irreducible chain has a unique steady state if and only if it is positive recurrent. Otherwise there may be multiple steady states which will depend on initial configuration of the chain. You can read more in detail on wikipedia or in Norris’ book *Markov Chains*, for example.